# How to compile node.js for CentOS 6.10 (library issues)

Tags: c++, node.js, linux, centos

I'm trying to get the newest version of node (12.1.0, at present) running on a CentOS 6.10 box.  This is a problem because the standard CentOS binaries are out of date; e.g.:

```
./node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./node)
(a number of other references like this also appear)
```

when I try to install and run the binaries, and the g++ / c++ tools are out of date.  But I've decided to try to compile from source, if I can get the tools properly aligned.

I've gotten an updated version of the compiler tools from the CERN devtools (http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/devtoolset), and seemingly have them installed properly.  What I've gotten from various places around the web is that I need to export pointers to these new libraries before doing the configure, like:

```
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc  
export CPP=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/cpp
export CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++
```

These do have the updated and sufficiently modern versions, e.g.,

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++ --version
c++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

But they don't seem to be getting into the configuration process:

```
[root@linux2 node-v12.1.0]# ./configure --prefix=/opt/node-12.1.0
WARNING: C++ compiler too old, need g++ 6.3.0 or clang++ 8.0.0 (CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/c++)
INFO: Using floating patch "tools/icu/patches/64/source/common/putil.cpp" from "tools/icu"
INFO: Using floating patch "tools/icu/patches/64/source/i18n/dtptngen.cpp" from "tools/icu"
WARNING: warnings were emitted in the configure phase
INFO: configure completed successfully
```

When I cross my fingers and try to `make` anyway, I get a whole bunch of compilation results and then a bunch of errors, omitted here (for now) for brevity.

Anyway: it's just not working.  Can anyone see what's going on here, and how I can get things right?  Thanks!

Comment: `need g++ 6.3.0 or clang++ 8.0.0` and you are using `4.8.2`

Comment: Thx to both, including @jamieguinan -- It took some doing, but I finally got devtoolset7 installed (after working around some dependency issues for sci-utils), and am up and running node-12.1.0.  (The c++ in devtoolset-2 was enough to compile node 12, but it broke on 'make install'.)  Thanks! (I'll give you an answer credit if you move your comment into an answer, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a newer devtoolset, 6 or 7 instead of 2. [This link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68077#p285857) should help. And use `scl` like it suggests instead of setting env vars yourself.